# Android numeric keyboard

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am trying to add a keyboard listener...

```
txta1cresult.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v,int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            calculate();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

However, I am getting the following compiler error...

```
/home/jocala/hba1c/src/com/android/hba1c.java:82: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class OnEditorActionListener
location: class com.jocala.hba1c.hba1c
txta1cresult.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
```

This is my `EditText`...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txta1cresult"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:layout_height="40px"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_x="200px"
    android:layout_y="32px"
    >
</EditText>
```

Do I need to import something other than `EditText` and `TextView`? Is there something else wrong here?

```
 [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/jeff/hba1c/bin/classes
  [javac] /home/jeff/hba1c/src/com/android/hba1c.java:83: cannot find symbol
  [javac] symbol: class KeyEvent
  [javac]     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
     [javac]                                                       ^
[javac] /home/jeff/hba1c/src/com/android/hba1c.java:84: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: variable EditorInfo
[javac]         if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
[javac]                      ^
[javac] 2 errors
```

2 errors remaining after fixing the import:

```
[javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/jeff/hba1c/bin/classes
[javac] /home/jeff/hba1c/src/com/android/hba1c.java:161: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: class KeyEvent
[javac]     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
[javac]                                                             ^
[javac] /home/jeff/hba1c/src/com/android/hba1c.java:162: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol: variable EditorInfo
[javac]         if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
[javac]                      ^
[javac] 2 errors
```

It appears to choke on this code:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        calculate();
    }
```

Finally fixed with:

import android.view.KeyEvent;
   import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

Thanks!

Comment: Help please?  Just learning java, if that's not obvious. Just want to perform an action when the soft keyboard 'done' is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to import [`TextView.OnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)

Relatedly, pay attention to the `KeyEvent` parameter. If the action was triggered by an Enter key (which sounds like what you want to do), it will be in that parameter. You might try that instead of gleaning it from the `int` parameter.

Comment: Thank you. The listener fails with 2 errors after correction. Thanks for any help.

Comment: import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener` in your code.

Or, change your listener from this...

```
txta1cresult.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
```

to this...

```
txta1cresult.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
```

The compiler error you're getting is basically saying that is doesn't know what `OnEditorActionListener` is, so you need to import it.

Comment: Thank you. The listener fails with 2 errors after correction. Thanks for any help.